# Compiled console command-line program doesn't wait for all the threads finishing

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#, mailboxprocessor

Some of the threads will be terminated before finished if the code is compiled to a console program or run as *fsi --use:Program.fs --exec --quiet*. Any way to wait for all the threads ending?

This issue can be described as "*program exit problem when multiple MailboxProcessers exist*".

**Output example**

(Note the last line is truncated and the last output function (`printfn "[Main] after crawl"`) is never executed.)

```
[Main] before crawl
[Crawl] before return result
http://news.google.com crawled by agent 1.
[supervisor] reached limit
Agent 5 is done.
http://www.gstatic.com/news/img/favicon.ico crawled by agent 1.
[supervisor] reached limit
Agent 1 is done.
http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=ni crawled by agent 4.
[supervisor] reached limit
Agent 4 is done.
http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=nw crawled by agent 2.
[supervisor] reached limit
Agent 2 is done.
http://news.google.
```

**Code**

*Edit: added several `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground <- false`.*

```
open System
open System.Collections.Concurrent
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO
open System.Net
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

module Helpers =

    type Message =
        | Done
        | Mailbox of MailboxProcessor<Message>
        | Stop
        | Url of string option
        | Start of AsyncReplyChannel<unit>

    // Gates the number of crawling agents.
    [<Literal>]
    let Gate = 5

    // Extracts links from HTML.
    let extractLinks html =
        let pattern1 = "(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"|\')/?((?!#.*|/\B|" + 
                       "mailto:|location\.|javascript:)[^\"\']+)(\"|\')"
        let pattern2 = "(?i)^https?"

        let links =
            [
                for x in Regex(pattern1).Matches(html) do
                    yield x.Groups.[2].Value
            ]
            |> List.filter (fun x -> Regex(pattern2).IsMatch(x))
        links

    // Fetches a Web page.
    let fetch (url : string) =
        try
            let req = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
            req.UserAgent <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 9.0; en-US)"
            req.Timeout <- 5000
            use resp = req.GetResponse()
            let content = resp.ContentType
            let isHtml = Regex("html").IsMatch(content)
            match isHtml with
            | true -> use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
                      use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
                      let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
                      Some html
            | false -> None
        with
        | _ -> None

    let collectLinks url =
        let html = fetch url
        match html with
        | Some x -> extractLinks x
        | None -> []

open Helpers

// Creates a mailbox that synchronizes printing to the console (so 
// that two calls to 'printfn' do not interleave when printing)
let printer = 
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun x -> async {
        while true do 
        let! str = x.Receive()
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground <- false
        printfn "%s" str })
// Hides standard 'printfn' function (formats the string using 
// 'kprintf' and then posts the result to the printer agent.
let printfn fmt = 
    Printf.kprintf printer.Post fmt

let crawl url limit = 
    // Concurrent queue for saving collected urls.
    let q = ConcurrentQueue<string>()

    // Holds crawled URLs.
    let set = HashSet<string>()


    let supervisor =
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun x -> async {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground <- false
            // The agent expects to receive 'Start' message first - the message
            // carries a reply channel that is used to notify the caller
            // when the agent completes crawling.
            let! start = x.Receive()
            let repl =
              match start with
              | Start repl -> repl
              | _ -> failwith "Expected Start message!"

            let rec loop run =
                async {
                    let! msg = x.Receive()
                    match msg with
                    | Mailbox(mailbox) -> 
                        let count = set.Count
                        if count < limit - 1 && run then 
                            let url = q.TryDequeue()
                            match url with
                            | true, str -> if not (set.Contains str) then
                                                let set'= set.Add str
                                                mailbox.Post <| Url(Some str)
                                                return! loop run
                                            else
                                                mailbox.Post <| Url None
                                                return! loop run

                            | _ -> mailbox.Post <| Url None
                                   return! loop run
                        else
                            printfn "[supervisor] reached limit" 
                            // Wait for finishing
                            mailbox.Post Stop
                            return! loop run
                    | Stop -> printfn "[Supervisor] stop"; return! loop false
                    | Start _ -> failwith "Unexpected start message!"
                    | Url _ -> failwith "Unexpected URL message!"
                    | Done -> printfn "[Supervisor] Supervisor is done."
                              (x :> IDisposable).Dispose()
                              // Notify the caller that the agent has completed
                              repl.Reply(())
                }
            do! loop true })


    let urlCollector =
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun y ->
            let rec loop count =
                async {
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground <- false
                    let! msg = y.TryReceive(6000)
                    match msg with
                    | Some message ->
                        match message with
                        | Url u ->
                            match u with
                            | Some url -> q.Enqueue url
                                          return! loop count
                            | None -> return! loop count
                        | _ ->
                            match count with
                            | Gate -> (y :> IDisposable).Dispose()
                                      printfn "[urlCollector] URL collector is done."
                                      supervisor.Post Done
                            | _ -> return! loop (count + 1)
                    | None -> supervisor.Post Stop
                              return! loop count
                }
            loop 1)

    /// Initializes a crawling agent.
    let crawler id =
        MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
            let rec loop() =
                async {
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground <- false
                    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                    match msg with
                    | Url x ->
                        match x with
                        | Some url -> 
                                let links = collectLinks url
                                printfn "%s crawled by agent %d." url id
                                for link in links do
                                    urlCollector.Post <| Url (Some link)
                                supervisor.Post(Mailbox(inbox))
                                return! loop()
                        | None -> supervisor.Post(Mailbox(inbox))
                                  return! loop()
                    | _ -> printfn "Agent %d is done." id
                           urlCollector.Post Done
                           (inbox :> IDisposable).Dispose()
                    }
            loop())

    // Send 'Start' message to the main agent. The result
    // is asynchronous workflow that will complete when the
    // agent crawling completes
    let result = supervisor.PostAndAsyncReply(Start)
    // Spawn the crawlers.
    let crawlers = 
        [
            for i in 1 .. Gate do
                yield crawler i
        ]

    // Post the first messages.
    crawlers.Head.Post <| Url (Some url)
    crawlers.Tail |> List.iter (fun ag -> ag.Post <| Url None) 
    printfn "[Crawl] before return result"
    result

// Example:
printfn "[Main] before crawl"
crawl "http://news.google.com" 5
|> Async.RunSynchronously
printfn "[Main] after crawl"
```

Comment: Could you simplify your code, so that is still exhibits the problem, but doesn't contain lots of irrelevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've sort of solved the problem: adding `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground <- false` after the `let!` in the printer agent.

However, I tried to modify the original code (the first version before Tomas' AsyncChannel fix) by adding `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground <- false` after all the `let!` and it still doesn't work. No idea.

Thanks everyone for your help. I finally can start my first F# application for a batch process. I think MailboxProcessor should really set IsBackground to false by default. Anyway to ask Microsoft to change it.

**[Update]** Just found out that the compiled assembly works well. But `fsi --user:Program --exec --quiet` is still the same. It seems a bug of fsi?

Comment: Feature suggestions can be sent to fsbugs@microsoft.com.

Comment: The Mailbox processors thread should be a background thread, as are all threadpool threads, you should be using control flow to stop program termination.

Answer (score 3):

If I recognize the code correctly, it is based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556102/f-mailboxprocessor-questions) (and my answer).

The program waits until the *supervisor agent* completes (by sending the `Start` message and then waiting for the reply using `RunSynchronously`). This should guarantee that the main agent as well as all crawlers complete before the application exits.

The problem is that it doesn't wait until the `printer` agent completes! So, the last call to the (redefined) `printfn` function sends a message to the agent and then the application completes without waiting until the printing agent finishes.

As far as I know, there is no "standard pattern" for waiting until agent completes processing all messages currently in the queue. Some ideas that you could try are:

- You could check the `CurrentQueueLength` property (wait until it is 0), but that still doesn't mean that the agent *completed* processing all messages.
- You could make the agent more complex by adding a new type of message and waiting until the agent replies to that message (just like you're currently waiting for a reply to the `Start` message).

Comment: Yes, it's based on my previous question and your answer. Thanks very much for the solution. It seems that all the agents other than supervisor also need the "Start" message and it can be much complex since there are (3 + 5) agents now. Just wonder if there is any better solution.

Comment: @NickW - The `supervisor` returns the `Done` message only after it receive `Done` message from all url collectors (that must recieve `Done` message from all crawlers). So, the supervisor should end only after all other (except for printer) complete. I think the solution is a bit too complex though. I'd probably use just one URL queue, maybe implemented using this agent: http://tomasp.net/blog/parallel-extra-blockingagent.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Caveat that I know zero F#, but typically you wait for all threads of interest using [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx).  It looks to me like in your case, you need to wait for anything of interest that's kicked off via a call to `.Start`.

You could also consider Task Parallel Library which gives you a higher level (simpler) abstraction onto raw managed threads.  Example for waiting for tasks to complete [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. The task parallel library seems not available in F# yet. I think the MailboxProcessor is a nice mechanism to handle this kind of tasks. It seems the MailboxProcessor doesn't have something like Thread.Join for multiple MailboxProcessers yet.

Comment: For what it's worth, TPL is 100% usable from F# (as are all .NET libraries). However, it may not have the syntactic sweetness one comes to expect from F# libraries. Also, for what you're code seems to be doing, I think MailboxProcessors are a good "fit".

Answer (score 0):

.NET threads have property Thread.IsBackground when this is set to true a thread will not prevent the process from exiting. When set to false it will prevent the process from exiting. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx

The threads that run agents come from the thread pool and therefore have Thread.IsBackground set to false by default.

You might try setting the thread's IsBackground to false each time you read a message. You could add a function to do this for you to make the approach cleaner. It's perhaps not the best solution to the problem as each time you use a let! you could change threads so it would need to be carefully implemented to work properly. I just thought mention it to answer the specific question

> Any way to wait for all the threads ending?

and help people understand why certain threads stop the program exiting and other’s didn’t.

Comment: Its the other way around isnt it?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx